# NY Times API -- Comments not being returned

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have code below that is intended to first try NY Times API & then bs4 for scraping with the goal of creating a data set of each comment on an article that I pass in via a link. In turn outputting some NLP data anlaysis. I am very close but also a bit conufused as my input returns the first pargraph of the article. Anyone have a fresh pair of eyes on feedbacked? Example input article here, which has comments: https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/11/nyregion/remote-work-hybrid-manhattan.html

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from newspaper import Article
from textblob import TextBlob
import requests
import json
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')


app = Flask(__name__)

def get_comments(api_key, article_id):
    url = f"url"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return None
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    comments = data['results']['comments']
    return comments

def process_article(article_url):
    article = Article(article_url)
    article.download()
    article.parse()

    api_key = 'secret'
    articles_url = f"https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q={article.title}&fq=source:(%{api_key}"
    response = requests.get(articles_url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return "Article not found on The New York Times."
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    articles = data['response']['docs']
    for a in articles:
        if article_url == a['web_url']:
            article_id = a['web_url']
            break
    else:
        return "Article not found on The New York Times."

    comments = get_comments(api_key, article_id)

    if comments is None:
        article.download()
        article.parse()
        article.nlp()
        return article.summary

    sentiment_polarity = 0
    sentiment_subjectivity = 0
    topics = {}
    for comment in comments:
        comment_body = comment['commentBody']
        sentiment = TextBlob(comment_body).sentiment
        sentiment_polarity += sentiment.polarity
        sentiment_subjectivity += sentiment.subjectivity
        if sentiment.polarity > 0:
            sentiment_label = 'positive'
        elif sentiment.polarity == 0:
            sentiment_label = 'neutral'
        else:
            sentiment_label = 'negative'
        for topic in comment['commentTitle'].split():
            if topic in topics:
                topics[topic][sentiment_label] += 1
            else:
                topics[topic] = {'positive': 0, 'neutral': 0, 'negative': 0}
                topics[topic][sentiment_label] += 1

    num_comments = len(comments)
    avg_sentiment_polarity = sentiment_polarity / num_comments
    avg_sentiment_subjectivity = sentiment_subjectivity / num_comments

    return render_template('results.html', 
                           article_title=article.title,
                           article_text=article.text,
                           num_comments=num_comments,
                           avg_sentiment_polarity=avg_sentiment_polarity,
                           avg_sentiment_subjectivity=avg_sentiment_subjectivity,
                           topics=topics)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article_url = request.form['article_url']
        try:
            return process_article(article_url)
        except:
            article = Article(article_url)
            article.download()
            article.parse()
            article.nlp()
            return article.summary
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get the comments from the New York Times API as *community data* is subject to commercial use of the API and, as of now, is **unavailable** through the NYT Developers Portal.

> The Times is no longer providing reader comments for non-commercial use cases via the Developer Portal.

This comes from the [NYT API FAQ](https://developer.nytimes.com/faq). Particularly, question number 13:

[13. What happened to the Community API?](https://developer.nytimes.com/faq#a13).

Good news is, they might have a *commercial* offering to access the community data this year (2023).

> We expect to have details regarding a commercial offering in 2023 and for further information, please contact nytlg-sales@nytimes.com.

---

As for the article's contents the best you can get is (see below to learn why):

> NY Times articles are paid, so it doesn't make any sense to make them available via a free API. :-]

- snippet
- abstract
- lead paragraph

Check the [schema](https://developer.nytimes.com/docs/articlesearch-product/1/types/Article).

Sample code:

```py
import textwrap

import requests


def wrap_line(text, width=80):
    return textwrap.fill(text, width=width, fix_sentence_endings=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"
    sample_article = "https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/11/nyregion/remote-work-hybrid-manhattan.html"
    build_query = (
        sample_article
        .rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
        .replace('.html', '')
        .replace('-', '+')
    )
    endpoint = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json"
    api_url = f"{endpoint}?api-key={API_KEY}&q={build_query}&sort=relevance"
    docs = requests.get(api_url).json()['response']['docs']
    for doc in docs:
        if doc['web_url'] == sample_article:
            print(wrap_line(doc['headline']['main']))
            print("-" * 80)
            print(wrap_line(doc['abstract']))
            print("-" * 80)
            print(wrap_line(doc['lead_paragraph']))
            break
```

Output:

```
As Remote Work Becomes Permanent, Can Manhattan Adapt?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
With more companies adopting hybrid work, New York City’s economy, which relies
on commuters and full office buildings, faces an uncertain future.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PwC, a global consulting firm with its American headquarters in New York City,
has told 40,000 of its United States employees that they can work remotely
forever.  Quinn Emanuel Urquhart & Sullivan, a white-shoe law firm with about
300 lawyers in New York, is allowing its staff to live anywhere in the country.
```

Comment: not quire the answer but apreciate the thorough detail and trailer park boys icon